# how to use irc, do u know any online chat tools for linux online help

Tags: linux

Can you please told we how we can use the irc (Internet relay chat) this name was just new to me ***what i heared about this is that this is online community for sharing various queries ... is there any other utilty through which we can share linux related queries through online chatting.
linux

Answer (score 2):

For using IRC there are basically 2 options:

- use a webchat
- or a "dedicated" Desktop-client

You also need to decide on the network you want to use, if you're looking for generic Linux help, you're probably best of trying your luck on either [freenode](http://freenode.net) or [OFTC](http://www.oftc.net/oftc/) - both have generic Linux help [channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat#Channels) as well as [channels for most distributions](http://irc.netsplit.de/channels/).

Regarding the client, most networks do offer a hosted webchat - take a look on their website to find out more.

Desktop clients are available for all platforms, both free / OSS and paid. Which client you use is a matter of personal taste - you might want to take a look at [this section](http://www.irc-wiki.org/Category:Standalone_IRC_clients) in the IRC-Wiki, as well as the [list of unfinished entries there](http://www.irc-wiki.org/Pages_To_Be_Completed#Clients).

Feel free to follow up if you want to know more :)

Comment: i had made login to OFTC as suggested by u but can u pleaze help that how can i join the chat room for this community as
i see link irc://irc.oftc.net:6667
but when i clicked on it gives eror - protocol (irc) isn't associated with any program.

Comment: As i said, you'll need an IRC client for that - just like you need a Browser for accessing this Page.

If you're using Firefox you might want to try ChatZilla: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/16/

Once you're connected you'll need to use the "/join" command to enter a/the channel:

/join #debian

Or, in case you're using an other distro search for appropiate channels here: http://irc.netsplit.de/channels/

For a basic introduction on how to use IRC see http://irchelp.org/irchelp/new2irc.html

Comment: Connecting to irc://irc.oftc.net/ (irc://irc.oftc.net/)… [Cancel]
 [ERROR] Connection to irc://irc.oftc.net/ (irc://irc.oftc.net/) timed out. [Help] Reconnecting in 30 seconds. [Cancel] ----------this error occurs instationously

Comment: hi phrozen ,

could u please help how cn i resolve Connecting to irc://irc.oftc.net/ (irc://irc.oftc.net/)… [Cancel] [ERROR] Connection to irc://irc.oftc.net/ (irc://irc.oftc.net/) timed out. [Help] Reconnecting in 30 seconds. [Cancel] ----------this error occurs instationously – sunil 56 mins ago error

Answer (score 0):

As far as using a web client goes, [Mibbit](http://www.mibbit.com/) is nice.